# How can I query MySQL to get the SUM of a COUNT?

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

I have a problem which asks: "Who is the top renter in the database?" and so far, I have it *almost* complete. At least, as far as I can tell.

What I have in the query so far is:

```
SELECT customer.first_name, customer.last_name, 
  COUNT(rental.rental_id) AS `Total Rentals` 
FROM customer
INNER JOIN rental
ON rental.customer_id = customer.customer_id
GROUP BY customer.last_name, rental.rental_id
ASC LIMIT 25;
```

The LIMIT 25 is only there for testing purposes, just to get two customers in the table so it's manageable.

This query yields:

```
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| first_name | last_name | Total Rentals |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |             1 |
| NATHANIEL  | ADAM      |             1 |
| NATHANIEL  | ADAM      |             1 |
| NATHANIEL  | ADAM      |             1 |
| NATHANIEL  | ADAM      |             1 |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Now, what I'm wanting is something like:

```
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| first_name | last_name | Total Rentals |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| RAFAEL     | ABNEY     |            22 |
| NATHANIEL  | ADAM      |            23 |
...
```

And so on.

I tried to do SUM(COUNT(rental.rental_id)), but apparently, that doesn't work due to execution order.

My question is what I need to do instead of that. I feel like I'm on the right track and there's one small thing I'm missing. Or, I could be horribly off.

Either way, thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL query - using SUM of COUNT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709747/mysql-query-using-sum-of-count)

Comment: Group by should be: `GROUP BY customer.customer_id`.  Since you only want 1 row per customer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customer.customer_id,
       customer.first_name, 
       customer.last_name, 
       COUNT(rental.rental_id) AS `Total Rentals` 
FROM customer
INNER JOIN rental
        ON rental.customer_id = customer.customer_id
GROUP BY customer.customer_id,
         customer.first_name, 
         customer.last_name  -- USE THIS GROUP BY
```

Comment: This query will incorrectly group different customers with same first name and last name.

Comment: @AlexLE I had that concern too, but this particular database does not have repeating names. I do realize that it's poor implementation, but for this particular problem, it shouldn't make a difference. To fix that, I'd just have to use the customer's assigned id, correct?

Comment: Just changed it to GROUP BY customer.customer_id and it seemed to do the same thing, so I assume this would be the proper way to handle it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: MySQL allow you do that kind of things, but those arent really ANSI Standard. I update my answer so now also include `customer_id`.

Comment: @TristinBaker. Sure, if the customer_id is added to the projection and the group by you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

First query the rental table group by customer_id:

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(rental_id) AS total
FROM rental
GROUP BY customer_id
```

then join the result to the customer table:

```
SELECT customer.first_name, customer.last_name, r.total AS `Total Rentals` 
FROM (
  SELECT customer_id, COUNT(rental_id) AS total
  FROM rental
  GROUP BY customer_id
) r
INNER JOIN customer ON r.customer_id = customer.customer_id
```

Comment: Your comment was right, but instead of create a sub query, I just add another level of group by.