# How to get the SUM of COUNT after using GROUP BY in SQL in an optimized way?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, phpmyadmin, sum

I am trying to get the SUM of the values of a column which is already using GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT 
    t.qid,
    COUNT(t.qid) AS total,
    ROUND(u.mental_age, 0) AS uma,
    AVG(t.correct) AS a
FROM
    test_data t
        INNER JOIN
    users u ON t.uid = u.id
WHERE
    u.guest = 0
GROUP BY t.qid , ROUND(u.mental_age, 0)
```

The above query gives the following output:

[image]

**I want the SUM of the COUNT of the total column GROUPED BY qid**

Example:

All the values in the total column with qid 3 should be 28 (2 + 9 + 8 + 6 + 3)

All the values in the total column with qid 4 should be 73 (5 + 7 + 19 + 7 + 13 + 9 + 9 + 2 + 1 + 1)

All the values in the total column with qid 5 should be 37 (3 + 8 + 16 + 7 + 2 + 1)

I have tried doing `SUM(COUNT(t.qid)) AS total` to get the SUM of the COUNT but it gives error because of the GROUP BY clause:

> #1111 - Invalid use of group function

How do I get the desired output?

**EDIT:**

A similar question has already been asked and answered here:
[MySQL query - using SUM of COUNT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709747/mysql-query-using-sum-of-count)

But it doesn't solve my problem. I forgot to mention that there are currently **158427** rows in the table. Using nested SELECT query as @nbk suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67436707/3359028

took **490.6096 seconds** to execute the query.
Also, it still didn't give the desired output.

The expected value of total column for qid 3 is 28. The solution that @nbk provided gave 126 instead.

[image]

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and produce a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

you can run suwqueries that prudices inly one values and use that as a column values.

If your subquery has more that one row as result or multiple cplumns you get an error

```
SELECT 
    t.qid,
    COUNT(t.qid) AS total,
    ROUND(u.mental_age, 0) AS uma,
    AVG(t.correct) AS a,
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM test_data WHERE qid = t.qid) SumTotal
FROM
    test_data t
        INNER JOIN
    users u ON t.uid = u.id
WHERE
    u.guest = 0
GROUP BY t.qid , ROUND(u.mental_age, 0)
```

Comment: the Query took 490.6096 seconds. And it didn't give the desired output as well. Sum of qid 3 is 126 instead of 28.
Is there any other optimized way to solve this?

Comment: you have post a [mre] so i don't know what you want, the result of my query is correct. Count are always very slow., so make a [mre] and then live with the result#